# Plotting characters in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to make a scatter plot in `R` where the points that are being plotted correspond to numbers.

```
x = 1:20
y = 1:20
plot(x,y,pch=as.character(1:20))
```

However, for all the numbers that have two digits, only the first digit gets plotted.  How can I make it so that 10,11,...,20 get plotted instead of 1,1,...,2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `text` command should do it for you.

```
x = 1:20
y = 1:20
plot(x,y,type = "n")
text(x, y, labels = 1:20)
```